# Find an integrable function $g$ on $[0,\infty)$ such that, $\frac{x}{e^{\lambda x}} < g(x)$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $\lambda_0 > 0 $ be a real number. I am trying to find an integrable function $g$ on $[0,\infty)$ such that, $$\frac{x}{e^{\lambda x}} < g(x) , \forall \lambda \in (\lambda_0,\infty), \forall x \in [0,\infty)$$

I've thought of $g(x)$ as, $$g(x) := (k+1)e^{- \lambda_0 x} \text{ , for } k \le x \le k+1$$

Does this work? If this does not work kindly provide examples.

Also what to do for the generalized problem

> Find an integrable function $g$ on $[0,\infty)$ such that,given any $n \in \Bbb N$ , $$\frac{x^n}{e^{\lambda x}} < g(x) , \forall \lambda \in (\lambda_0,\infty), \forall x \in [0,\infty), $$

In this case, will it work defining some thing like, $$g(x) := (k+1)^ne^{- \lambda_0 x} \text{ , for } k \le x \le k+1$$

Give some example if this doesn't work.

Comment: Your example on the first one works. The second question seems to be asking for a function $g$ that works for any $n$, which is impossible. For fixed $n$ your example is fine.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested before  $g(x)=2\frac{x}{e^{\lambda x}}$ could be an option, and you can prove that this functions is integrable in $[0,\infty)$

$$\int_0^\infty 2xe^{-\lambda x}dx=\frac{2}\lambda\int_0^\infty x\lambda e^{-\lambda x} dx$$

on the right hand you have $\frac{2}\lambda$ multiplying the expected value of a Exponential R.V. which is equal to $\lambda^{-1}$ which proves that it's integrable.

I don't know if I am getting your point, I'm just trying to find a simple example. Let me know!

Answer (score 0):

How about $g(x)=2\cdot\frac{x}{e^{\lambda x}}$?

Comment: But then again, you have to give a prove that function is integrable. So  my example doesn't work?